# The for loop in my python function is not running

Tags: python, pygame, logic

My for loop inside the function "play()" is not getting executed at runtime.

```
def play():
    print("1")
    for files in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        if files.endswith("mp3"):
            print("2")
            pygame.mixer.Sound.play(files)
        else:
            continue
play()
```

Comment: Did you actually call the `play` function anywhere?

Comment: What is the output of `os.listdir(os.getcwd())`?

Comment: Yes I did because the print("1") function is executed but nothing else.

Comment: The output of os.listdir(os.getcwd()) is the current directory in a string

Comment: So, you see a `"1"` printed, but not a `"2"`? And there are files ending with `mp3` in there? For good measure, add `print(files)` before the `if` on line 4; see if that prints the name of the file. (I guess the variable should be called `file` but that's tangential.)

Answer (score 0):

`pygame` seems a poor choice for a media player, unless you have it loaded for another reason.
I'd suggest you look on SO for `vlc.py` or `Gstreamer` examples.
That said, the player can only play one thing at a time, so you can't just throw the contents of your disk at it and you need to check if you found anything at all.
For `pygame.mixer.Sound` see the second piece of code.

Try something like this as your starting point:

```
import os
import pygame.mixer
import time

pygame.mixer.init(frequency=44100)
def play():
    loaded = 0
    queue = []
    path = os.getcwd()
    for mp3 in os.listdir(path):
        if mp3.endswith("mp3"):
            if loaded == 0:
                pygame.mixer.music.load(mp3)
                loaded = 1
                print('Playing:', mp3)
            else:
                print('Queued:', mp3)
                queue.append(mp3)                

    print("\nAudio Queued: ", str(len(queue)), "\n")
    running = True
    if loaded:
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        while running:
            time.sleep(1)
            if not pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
                if len(queue):
                    pygame.mixer.music.load(queue[0])
                    print('Playing:', queue[0])
                    queue.pop(0)
                    pygame.mixer.music.play()
                else:
                    running = False
    else:
        print("No media found in ", path)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    play()
```

**Beware** the `frequency` setting in the `init`.
You may have to load other modules to determine what it is for each audio item and re-init the player, to enforce it. Otherwise, you may find things playing at the wrong tempo.

Edit: However, if you are merely trying to play sound effects, it should be noted that `pygame.mixer.Sound` only documents `wav` and `ogg` files **not** `mp3` and the throwing them all at it at the same time still holds true.

Try something based on this:

```
import os
import pygame.mixer
import time
pygame.mixer.init(frequency=44100)
#path = os.getcwd()
path = "/usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/"
def play(path):
    print("1")
    for sound in os.listdir(path):
        if sound.endswith("ogg"):
            sound = path+sound
            print(sound)
            try:
                mysound = pygame.mixer.Sound(sound)
                mysound.play()
                time.sleep(10)
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error "+sound+" "+str(e))
                continue
        else:
            continue
play(path)
```

Note that `pygame.mixer.Sound` requires the full path of the sound file

Answer (score -1):

Okay, so just reproduced the error. Found out you were missing on few imports/ functions. Here is the code you need to run.

```
import os
import pygame.mixer
pygame.mixer.init()
def play():
    print("1")
    for files in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        if files.endswith("mp3"):
            print(files)
            pygame.mixer.music.load(files)
            pygame.mixer.music.play()
        else:
            print("No such file exists")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    play()
```

I guess you were not initiating the mixer function. Also make sure you have mp3 file in your cwd. You can print cwd and ensure mp3 file is there.

You dont need nulll and print("1") as well.